# Guidelines when splitting artifact repositories

Tags: maven, nexus, artifactory, archiva

I am looking for an article which describes a set of guidelines to follow when creating repositories in an artifact repository manager.

I know that:

- You need to keep snapshots in snapshot repositories.
- You need to keep releases in release repositories.
- Third-party artifacts should be in a separate repository (the same goes for forked/patched 
  versions of third-party libraries).
- It's generally a good idea to prefix the names with `int-*` and `ext-*`.
- Usually different product lines end up having their own repositories as sometimes their artifacts don't depend on each other.

I've been trying to find an article on this to illustrate to a client how this artifact separation abstraction is done by other companies and organizations using repositories.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't artifactory start you off with a good structure after you install it?

Comment: Well, Nexus does as well. The question is more about what rules to follow when creating new repositories and deciding when you need one for a set of artifacts.

Comment: From my experience, what you mentioned are basically the standard rules. i haven't seen any articles talking about this though

Answer (score 7):

I am not aware of existence of such an article, but as @tieTYT  mentioned, you can look at Artifactory default repositories. They reflect years of experience in binaries management, continuous integration and delivery. 
Those practices still apply even if you use Nexus (and you can observe them even without installing Artifactory, by looking at JFrog public Artifactory instance http://repo.jfrog.org)

For your convenience, here are the defaults (important usage *emphasised*):

**Local Repositories:**

- `libs-snapshot-local`: *Deploy here your local snapshots*
- `libs-release-local`: *Deploy here your local releases*
- `ext-snapshot-local`: Deploy here 3rd-party snapshots which aren't available in remote repos
- `ext-release-local`: Deploy here 3rd-party releases which aren't available in remote repos
- `plugins-snapshot-local`: Deploy here your plugin (usually, maven) snapshots
- `plugins-release-local`: Deploy here your plugin (usually, maven)  releases

**Remote Repositories:**

- `jcenter`: proxy of http://jcenter.bintray.com. Normally, that's the only remote repo you'll need. It includes whatever exists in maven central plus all other major maven repositories

**Virtual Repositories:**

- `remote-repos`: aggregation of all the remote repositories
- `libs-release`: *this is the resolution repository for release builds*. It includes `remote-repos`, `libs-release-local` and `ext-release-local`
- `libs-snapshot`: *this is the resolution repository for snapshot builds*. It includes `remote-repos`, `libs-snapshot-local` and `ext-shapshot-local`
- `repo`: this is special virtual repository, that aggregates everything. Generally, *do not use it*, if you ever plan building release pipeline using binary repository.

I'll be glad to advice on specific question.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question. It is not an article and it is not a guideline to follow, especially if the OP uses nexus

Comment: Could you point out what those recommended repositories are? There are a ton of them on the repo you linked to and I doubt you meant all of them.

Comment: @JBaruch: Thanks for sharing your thoughts as well. Maybe you should also put a disclaimer you're representing JFrog/Artifactory. I can see an upside of using jcenter, but I do not really agree with using it instead of Maven Central, as it hides a lot of repositories for you and could cause you routing rule confusion. You should know where things are coming from. I understand you're trying to promote your product. However, if you have an OSS project that you'd like to push to Maven Central, if you have any `<repositories/>` defined in your project, `oss.sonatype.org` will fail the staging.

Comment: The disclaimer appears clearly when you hover over my userpic (just compare it with @ManfredMoser whose relationship with Sonatype isn't stated in any way). 
Regarding jcenter, looks like you are a bit confused. I didn't recommend adding it to your local maven installation (although it's very easy to do without violating the oso requirements). It is just convenient remote repository setup in Artifactory, which simplifies and speeds up the resolution, not complicates it (one repo instead of a chain). But no problem, go ahead and add maven-central, java.net, codehaus, etc, etc.

Comment: Also @JBaruch ... all my projects are on my website including the stuff I do for Sonatype. But I do lots of other stuff too..

Comment: Np, @ManfredMoser, my only comment was regarding the requirement of carlspring to disclose my affinity with JFrog. While I state it in my bio, I had to digg into LinkedIn to discover your affinity with Sonatype (well, I don't, because I know the name, but others might have to).

Comment: @JBaruch, Thanks and -- yeah, I'd prefer having the repositories grouped in our repository (for a better understanding of what's happening). Are you mirroring Maven Central, codehaus et al behind that URL or are they served on demand? Either way, it looks great and I can see how and why it would be quick. BTW, java.net has been obsolete for a while now, as the artifacts in it became part of Maven Central like... a couple of years ago, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Bintray won't add another layer of complication, it, in fact, simplify things to you. It's not another proxy on the way, Bintray actually hosts all those artifacts. It's not a proxy, and even not a mirror, it's just a repository that has EVERYTHING. Re java.net - I have no clue, I used repo.jfrog.org for everything up until January and now Bintray instead. So even if (when) maven central will die, I won't notice :) You shouldn't too :)

Answer (score 2):

As is the case with many questions about best practices, the answer is: It depends.

Technically there are only two distinctions that are required:

- Snapshot vs release repo
- Hosted vs proxy repository

Snapshots vs release repositories as a distinction is required since the Maven repository format and therefore Maven and other build tools differentiate how they work with the the meta data and what they do during upload.

For proxy repositories you will just have to add as many you need to proxy. This will depend on what components you require and will be separate for proxying snapshot and release repos.

For hosted repositories you also have to have separate snapshot and release repos. Beyond that is is all up for grabs. Having a separate third party repo as preconfigured in Nexus (and Artifactory) and other setups are certainly useful, but not really necessary. You can have all those distinctions sorted out by internal meta data where required.

Along the same lines you can have one release repo for everyone or one for each team or whatever. You can still apply access rights within those repositories to separate access and so on in Nexus with repository targets. I assume Artifactory and Archiva can do something similar. The question here mostly boils down to ease of administration, backups, security setup and access for users.

Naming conventions like you mentioned can help if you want to have separate repositories, but technically none of this is necessary.

Other things I have seen are e.g. migration repos that are used to migrate legacy project libraries into a repo but become frozen after the migration is done, separate repos per team, separate repos per project and so on. Another aspect are separate repos for different levels of approval and so on (e.g. check out problems with that on http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2013/10/golden-repository/)

In the end however this all hinges really on usability and meta data and is not required. Ultimately these repositories will in most cases grouped together and accessed via one group, which flattens out the whole separation. And access rights still carry through into the group so everything can still be controlled as you like. So it turns to be a matter of taste on how you want to slice and dice and manage it.

PS: I am referring to the Maven repositories and format. Once you add a whole bunch of other formats into the mix and wrappers around them exposing them in other formats, everything gets more complicated, but the ideas behind things stay similar.

Comment: In my opinion, the part you mention about two types of repositories being "technically" sufficient, is not really advisable, for a large organization, as you have no place for your third-party dependencies. Unless you mean two types apart from the pre-defined ones that the server comes with.

Comment: I also have to disagree with the anonymous downvote for this answer. @Whoever-it-was, please kindly justify your reason.

Comment: Technically (I am not saying it is advisable, but purely technically) you can put third party components into your release repo and you will still see that they are third party since they should have different groupIds. Practically one or even multiple third party repos are probably better.

Comment: Yeah... One third-party repository for unmodified artifacts and one for forked projects that have been customized and patched by the company.

Comment: You could have multiple third party repos e.g. for different suppliers if you e.g. use commmerical, closed source components. But you could also just lump it all together in one repo and use meta data (e.g. with the custom metadata plugin) to differentiate components and put data like source and so on with the components.

Comment: Interesting, could you pass me a link to that plugin? I've never come across it. Is this a Nexus, or Maven plugin?

Comment: It is a Nexus plugin that lets you add arbitrary key value pairs to a component. Docs are here http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/custom-metadata-plugin.html